# ASP.NET Deserialize Form POST with unusual key names into proper DataContract model?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core

I'm somewhat new to C# and ASP.NET, and I've been tasked with replacing an application with a new ASP.NET Core MVC API service. I also have a legacy application that needs to POST some data into it, but I have no control over it's code and cannot change it's behavior. It wants to send data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, and with uppercased parameter names containing "invalid" characters when mapped back to a POCO data contract object, such as `.`, or names starting with numbers.

An example request from the legacy app might look like:

```
POST /something HTTP/1.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 42

USERNAME=somebody&ACCOUNT=123&APP.SESSID=acbd18db4cc2f85cedef654fccc4a4d8&1STCOLOR=BLUE
```

Since I cannot, and somewhat don't want, to create a DataContract model like this invalid code, I'm not sure how to proceed.

```
class InputModel
{
    public string USERNAME { get; set; }
    public int ACCOUNT { get; set; }
    public string APP.SESSID { get; set; }
    public string 1STCOLOR { get; set; }
}
```

Preferably, I'd like to humanize the data model member names where possible, (eg, `APP.SESSID` to `ApplicationSessionID`), and be able to bind the legacy parameter names to the humanized member names on deserialization of the form data, or during model binding, or something.

I just don't know where to look or what to search for in the ASP.NET Core code to help me determine what I should be doing to override the default form deserialization behavior. Can anyone with experience here help? Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. I first had to create a `ValueProvider` object. This is what I came up with.

```
public class MyValueProvider : BindingSourceValueProvider, IValueProvider
{
    private IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> _keyMap;
    private readonly CultureInfo _culture;
    private PrefixContainer _prefixContainer;
    private IFormCollection _values;

    public MyValueProvider(BindingSource form, IFormCollection values, CultureInfo culture) : this(form, values, null, culture) { }

    public MyValueProvider(BindingSource form, IFormCollection values, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> keyMap, CultureInfo culture) : base(form)
    {
        if (form == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(form));
        }

        if (values == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(values));
        }


        _values = values;
        _culture = culture;
        _keyMap = keyMap;
    }

    public CultureInfo Culture
    {
        get { return _culture; }
    }

    protected PrefixContainer PrefixContainer
    {
        get
        {
            if (_prefixContainer == null)
            {
                _prefixContainer = new PrefixContainer(_values.Keys);
            }
            return _prefixContainer;
        }
    }

    public override bool ContainsPrefix(string prefix)
    {
        return PrefixContainer.ContainsPrefix(prefix);
    }

    public virtual IDictionary<string, string> GetKeysFromPrefix(string prefix)
    {
        if (prefix == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(prefix));
        }

        return PrefixContainer.GetKeysFromPrefix(prefix);
    }

    public override ValueProviderResult GetValue(string key)
    {
        if (key == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(key));
        }

        var pair = _keyMap.FirstOrDefault(map => map.Key.EndsWith(key));
        if (pair.Value == null)
        {
            return ValueProviderResult.None;
        }
        var values = _values[pair.Value];
        if (values.Count == 0)
        {
            return ValueProviderResult.None;
        }

        return new ValueProviderResult(values, Culture);
    }
}
```

and then a Factory for that value provider.

```
public class MyValueProviderFactory : IValueProviderFactory
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>> keyMap;

    public MyValueProviderFactory(IConfigurationSection section)
    {
        keyMap = section.AsEnumerable();
    }

    public Task CreateValueProviderAsync(ValueProviderFactoryContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        if (context.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request.HasFormContentType)
        {
            return AddValueProviderAsync(context, keyMap);
        }

        return TaskCache.CompletedTask;
    }

    private static async Task AddValueProviderAsync(ValueProviderFactoryContext context, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> keyMap)
    {
        var request = context.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request;
        var valueProvider = new MyValueProvider(
                BindingSource.Form,
                await request.ReadFormAsync(),
                keyMap,
                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

        context.ValueProviders.Add(valueProvider);
    }
}
```

And then finally, in my `Startup` class, I load a section of my `appsettings.json` configuration as the key map. This is just a JSON object with the original key name as the JSON property, and the new key name as the value. I pass this as a bunch of key-values to my ValueProviderFactory, and then I insert this value provider factory into the front of the list of factories provided by the system.

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.ValueProviderFactories.Insert(0, new MyValueProviderFactory(Configuration.GetSection("MyValueProviderKeyMap")));
        });
    }
}
```

At the end, it's pretty straightforward. It just took me a bit to figure out the process.